# Realm: Results<T> als List<T>

Tags: ios, swift, realm

Is it possible to convert `Results<T>` to `List<T>` or shouldn't I do this?

In my case I have method that has List as a parameter. I want to call this method with fetched objects (`Results<T>`) and with computed objects (`List<T>`)

Comment: Can you leverage the fact that they are both `RealmCollectionType` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can use extensions to make life easier :

```
extension Realm {
    func list<T: Object>(_ type: T.Type) -> List<T> {
        let objects = self.objects(type)
        let list = objects.reduce(List<T>()) { list, element -> List<T> in
            list.append(element)
            return list
        }
        
        return list
    }
}
```

Usage:

```
let objects = realm.list(YourObject.self)
```

Answer (score 25):

`Results` implements the `CollectionType` protocol so you could use `reduce` to convert it:

```
let results: Results<MyObject> = ...
let converted = results.reduce(List<MyObject>()) { (list, element) -> List<MyObject> in
    list.append(element)
    return list
}
```

You could put this code in an extension or however you like.

Answer (score 5):

`Results` and `List` implement `CollectionType` and `RealmCollectionType`. The latter is a specialization of the former protocol, which allows you to efficiently use aggregation functions and filter & sort entries.

Almost no method in Realm Swift make strong assumptions about the type of the collection. They just expect a `SequenceType` which is a generalization of the former `CollectionType`. For your own method, I'd recommend to go the same way. You can reach that by declaring it like shown below.

```
func foo<T, S: SequenceType where S.Generator.Element == T>(objects: S) { … }
```

Answer (score 3):

I would create an extension for `Results` with a computed variable:

```
extension Results {
  var list: List<Element> {
    reduce(.init()) { list, element in
      list.append(element)
      return list
    }
  }
}
```

Then you can use it like this:

```
// results is a variable of type Results<SomeElement>
let list = results.list
```