# Covert realm list to realm result

Tags: swift, realm

just wondering, how do I convert List to Result?

Cause I'm doing filtering of region and areas, and when user selected region then area should show only those area in the region. And when I'm asigning my areas to a variable defined as `var areas: Results<Area>!`, I got the compile error

> Cannot assign value of type 'List' to type 'Results!'

my code is as below

```
if let regionString = self.selectedRegionString {
    let region = self.realm.objects(Region).filter("name = '\(regionString)'").first
    self.areas = region!.areas //this line is the problem
} else {
    self.areas = self.realm.objects(Area)
}
```

Answer (score 4):

I think you should define your `self.areas` like

```
var areas: List<Area>
```

It should have the same model class

`Results` is used for Realm's queries returned value.

Comment: if i change it to List<area> then the else {} clause will have a compile error saying result cannot be list

Comment: And it is correct. In `else {}` you are doing query and receive `Results` class. You should convert it to the List manually.

Comment: Also you can use `RealmCollectionType` . More info is here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33363972/realm-resultst-als-listt